# My formview wont change modes C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a FormView that has an ItemTemplate, EditItemTemplate and InsertItemTemplate. I recently changed from VB to C# and my VB version worked perfectly. From what I can tell the only difference in the two versions is the datasource. My VB FormView used SqlDataSource, my C# is using EntityFramework. The DefaultMode is set to ReadOnly and when I click the Edit Command button I get a post back but the FormView doesn't change. If I click the button a second time I get the following error.

```
Line: 6
Error: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Failed to load
viewstate.  The control tree into which viewstate is being loaded must
match the control tree that was used to save viewstate during the previous
request.  For example, when adding controls dynamically, the controls added
during a post-back must match the type and position of the controls added
during the initial request.
```

I have

```
protected void FormView1_ModeChanging(object sender, FormViewModeEventArgs e)
{

}
```

because I was getting an error saying that I didn't have the ModeChanging event handled.
Here is my EditButton_Click()

```
protected void EditButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   //I know that the FormView is supposed to automatically ChangeModes when the editbutton
    //is clicked. However, I have tried with and without the below statement.
    FormView1.ChangeMode(FormViewMode.Edit);
}
```

I fill my FormView with data using EntityFramework

```
//This is in my pages codeBehind
protected void ViewPartnerBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<FTP_GET_TESTING> dataList = ftpGetData.GetFTPSetup(FTPLookupDDL.SelectedValue);
    FormView1.DataSource = ftpGetData.GetFTPSetup(FTPLookupDDL.SelectedValue);
    FormView1.DataBind();
    FormView1.ChangeMode(FormViewMode.ReadOnly);

}
 //This is in my dataAccess class
 public List<FTP_GET_TESTING> GetFTPSetup(String ftpLookupId)
{
    using (Entities myEntities = new Entities())
    {
        var allFields = (from ftpGet in myEntities.FTP_GET_TESTING
                         where ftpGet.FTP_LOOKUP_ID == ftpLookupId
                         select ftpGet).ToList();

        return allFields;
    }
}
```

**More info**
My formview is contained within an update panel and I have tried a scriptManager in my master page, I have tried adding a scriptManagerProxy in my contentPage and I have also tried removing the scriptManager from the master and adding it directly to the contentPage.

Comment: I do not believe your problem is related to that control or the data.  I believe you have an Ajax or update panel problem.  Please look at and if you need to post your aspx markup.

Comment: Ok I have added some info about my aspx page. I didn't post the markup because I thought it might confuse matters with how many different methods I have tried.

Comment: Unfortunately that information doesn't help me.  My best suggestion is the create a vanilla web site and copy and paste your markup into a basic page with no ajax, no update panels, no user controls, and no master pages.  See if that works.  If not you can isolate your code issue.  If it does then you can start adding pieces back in and see which part is not working.

Comment: Thank you. I have decided to forgo the formview and just manually create a similar effect with buttons and enabling/disabling fields and the like for editing, viewing and inserting. Doing so gives me more control over the behavior of my site anyway and I think I should have done it this way from the beginning.